# Sending HTML Code Through JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, json

I've got a php script which generates HTML content.  Is there a way to send back that HTML content through JSON to my webpage from the php script?

Comment: If you're just sending markup back, why JSON encode at all?

Comment: because a plugin and it has some limitations...

Comment: You might want a conditional action based on the response i.e if operation successful then show HTML, if failed show appropriate error message

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to take your HTML string and escape it as necessary to be valid [JSON](http://json.org) (it'll also do things that are unnecessary, sadly, unless you use flags to prevent it). For instance, if your original string is:

```text
<p class="special">content</p>
```

...`json_encode` will produce this:

```text
"<p class=\"special\">content<\/p>"
```

You'll notice it has an unnecessary backslash before the `/` near the end. You can use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag to prevent the unnecessary backslashes. `json_encode(theString, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` produces:

```text
"<p class=\"special\">content</p>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Do Like this

1st put all your HTML content to array, then do `json_encode`

```
$html_content="<p>hello this is sample text";
$json_array=array(

'content'=>50,
'html_content'=>$html_content
);
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

```
$out = array(
   'render' => utf8_encode($renderOutput), 
   'text' => utf8_encode($textOutput)
);

$out = json_encode($out);
die($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
$data = "<html>....";
exit(json_encode($data));
```

Then you should use AJAX to retrieve the data and do what you want with it. I suggest using JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

You can send it as a String, why not. But you are probably missusing JSON here a bit since as far as I understand the point is to send just the data needed and wrap them into HTML on the client.

Comment: The data needed might be HTML

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @T.J. Crowder's answer.

`json_encode` does well with simple html strings, in my experience however `json_encode` often becomes confused by, (or it becomes quite difficult to properly escape) longer complex nested html mixed with php. Two options to consider if you are in this position are: encoding/decoding the markup first with something like `[base64_encode][1]`/ [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) (quite a bit of a performance hit), or (and perhaps preferably) be more selective in what you are passing via json, and generate the necessary markup on the client side instead.

Answer (score 1):

All these answers didn't work for me.

But this one did:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056253/2363481).