# How can I send HTML over JSON (in JS / Node)

Tags: html, json, node.js

I'm trying to return an html snippet from a service **that can only return valid JSON**.

I've tried some things like:

This gets me a bunch of character like \n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t

```
return JSON.stringify({html: $('body').html()});
```

or

```
return JSON.stringify($('body').html());
```

On the receiving end, I'd like to be able to parse that HTML via Cheerio, or jQuery or JSDom so I can then run queries like **$(".some_selector")** on that data.

What is the proper way of doing this? Any special libraries / methods that can handle the escaping for me? I've googled it, but haven't had any clear results...

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this would help? [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

On the receiving end, you need to simply undo the JSON serialization.  That's it!

Your HTML will be in its regular format at `obj.html`, which you can then parse with whatever DOM parser you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are probably going to need to worry about quotes in the HTML (like with attributes) because the could interfere with the quotes that delimit your JSON values.

Here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064561/sending-html-code-through-json) as well as [this web page](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) that explains some of what you need to consider.

Briefly looking at npmsj.org, I didn't see any reputable modules that might help you make HTML JSON compatible, but I think you can probably figure it out fairly easily on your own, given a large enough sample set of HTML. You can always run your JSON through [this validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check it. I suppose you could also simply do a JSON.parse(jsonContainingHtml) on it as well. You'll get an exception if the string is not valid JSON.