# Read file using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am making an application using node.js with express.js, and instead of using JADE, I am using EJS (Embedded Javascript).
 When I send(response) information to be plugged into my template I usually send as  JSON file, but sometimes I want the JSON file have  big chunk of HTML code. This is what I have:

1. JSON File
2. index.js (to send response)
3. blogPost.html

This is what I need:

1. Get blog post into the JSON file
2. Send it through index.js and make the server send the template with the HTML code...

I need:

```
{
    "title": "Test blog post",
    "paragraph": fs.readFileSync(blogPost.html)
}
```

replace the fs.readFileSync() with whatever I would use in JSON to read a file.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results/2001471#2001471), JSON is a data description language, not a programming language. Therefore, it is not possible to execute a function within JSON. I would execute the `fs.readFileSync` when the request is made to your server and include that data as a variable within the JSON model response itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064590/4259509) for more on that, although they're discussing it within the context of PHP, similar principles should apply. [This blog post](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) should help as well. Note the intricacy involved in making sure the proper characters are escaped and everything is formatted correctly.

**EDIT**

[Here(validator.js)](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) is a nice module to help with the html escaping/validation before you send it off with the rest of the JSON.